# I can't show an image from CGI

Tags: javascript, c, bash, apache, cgi

I am making an album of photos that are downloaded from https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/, but I encountered the problem that I cannot display an image, I already tried chmod 777 to the folder and also

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/local/apache2/img>
   Order Deny,Allow
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

echo '<html>'
echo '<head>'
echo '</head>'
echo '<body>'
echo '<h1>ALBUN DE FOTOS</h1>'
echo '<img src=img/imagen.jpg alt="imagen rota">'
echo "<p>hola</p>"
echo '</body>'
echo '</html>'

exit 0
```

Comment: I am using apache2 server

Comment: You should NEVER chmod to 777. Look at the apache error log, what is the message ? Also, what do you see if you 'curl' the URL from the command line ?

Comment: End of script output before headers: imagen.jpg, referer: http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/app1.cgi

Comment: Is app1.cgi the above bash script ?

Comment: Can you provide ls `-l app1.cgi`. The error message usually indicate non-executable file. Also where is the image located. As per script, it placed under the 'img' sub folder for the folder hosting app1.cgi. Is it marked for execution ?

Comment: Probably `/img/image.jpg` if the script is in `cgi-bin` dir